# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: | DeprecationWarning: | Mongoose 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In building a basic practice Chat app in node.js I've come across the above issue.

#### My express.js code :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://ChatbotAdmin:ChatbotAdmin@ds239177.mlab.com:39177/learning_node'
mongoose.connect(dbUrl,  (err) => {
console.log('Connected')
})
```

#### This is the full error:

```
(node:10192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 
ds239177.mlab.com:39177 closed
(node:10192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried adding {useMongoClient: true}, as did this fellow [The options [useMongoClient] is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031029/the-options-usemongoclient-is-not-supported)
. Only to find as he did that in mongoose 5, its not necessary (and doesn't help).

I further researched the addition of :

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
```

I had the same error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479632/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-unhandled-promise-rejection-rejection-id-1) Question also did not help.

I would just fallback on an earlier version of mongoose but I'm curious to see what the solution will be...

Comment: Just to be clear, there are no promises used in the rest of the code.

Comment: handle promise in your when you get any result from mongoose

Comment: @ManjeetThakur that was not clear. Plus as I just mentioned I'm not using any promises yet.

Comment: The real error is `MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 
ds239177.mlab.com:39177 closed`, which comes from mongodb-core.

Comment: @MikaS Which means what exactly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am stuck on the same thing -- am going against the mlab mongodb hosting and this stuff used to work in other projects.

Comment: I dropped it after spending quite a bit of time on it. I have a feeling it has to do with a connection issue to mlab but I don't have any "hard proof".

Answer (score 1):

You should get a third party promise library like bluebird.
See this below:

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
DBURL = process.env.DBURL;

var options = {
useMongoClient: true,
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30
};

mongoose.connect(DBURL, options);
db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', err => {
  console.log('There was a db connection error');
});
db.once('connected', () => {
  console.log('Successfully connected to ' + DBURL);
});
db.once('disconnected', () => {
  console.log('Successfully disconnected from ' + DBURL);
});
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  mongoose.connection.close(() => {
    console.log('dBase connection closed due to app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Bluebird will help you remove the deprecation error. I hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

I had some how the same issue.This issue  tend to appear whenever i use mlab mongodb but ok whenever i use my local db.I passed some options for tuning mongoose as described by mongoose official website https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html 
    
`const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
    reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
    poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
    // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000, // Give up initial connection after 10 seconds
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000, 
    family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
};
mongoose.connect(my_mongo_url,options);`

somehow that solved it for me

Comment: I passed the options for tuning mongoose as described https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Answer (score 0):

> try this code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});

//----------------------------
 Second option

// connect to  mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/peppino-calc', {
  useMongoClient: true
})
.then(() => { console.log('MongoDB connected...')})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: i have edit my answer please check if this is working for you

Comment: can you tell me your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
{ useNewUrlParser: true }
```

instead of:

```
useMongoClient: true
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you wrap your code in a try catch?

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
 var dbUrl = 'mongodb://ChatbotAdmin:ChatbotAdmin@ds239177.mlab.com:39177/learning_node'

 try {
   mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useMongoClient: true })
 } catch(e) { console.log(e.message) }
```